# oracle apex custom authorization scheme

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to create custom authorization schemes in my application.
1. isAdmin
2. isStaff
3. isMember

so I created those schemes and I also created three entries in the APEX_APPLICATION_PRIV (Admin, Staff, Member)

Now through the access control page I can grant each user one of the privileges, but how to connect each scheme to its privilege, so the page with authorization scheme isMember would appear only to those who has the privilege Member?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm kind of confused as to why you don't just use the default (administrator, edit, view) for your ACL, instead of going through the trouble of having custom ones.

Couldn't you represent your authorization scheme (Admin, Staff, Member) exactly as the default ACL authorization schemes (administrator, edit, view).  Where Admin - administrator, Staff - edit, and Member - view.  Seems a lot less painful.

[Here is the oracle documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E39147_04/bldapp_acc.htm)

Edit:
Here is the PL/SQL code returning a boolean value used for the default authorization scheme 'administrator' created by the ACL.

```
declare
  l_setup_id number;
  l_mode     varchar2(50);
  l_priv     varchar2(50);
begin
  if apex_application.is_custom_auth_page then
    return true;
  end if;

  for c1 in (select id, application_mode
             from apex_access_setup 
             where application_id = :app_id)
  loop
    l_setup_id := c1.id;
    l_mode := c1.application_mode;
  end loop;

  if (l_mode = 'ALL') or (l_mode is null) then
    return true;
  end if;

  for c1 in (select admin_privileges 
             from apex_access_control
             where upper(admin_username) = upper(:app_user)
             and setup_id = l_setup_id)
  loop
    l_priv := c1.admin_privileges;
  end loop;

  if nvl(l_priv,'x') = 'ADMIN' then return true; end if;
  return false;
end;
```

In your case I imagine you could just replace the 'ADMIN' with 'isAdmin' (or however you specified it in your DB).  Then have additional PL/SQL functions appropriately returning true or false for the Staff and Members.

I believe you can only have one authorization scheme per page/item so keep this in mind.  The default authorization schemes take care of this by admin being able to access everything users with edit and view privileges can.  Users with edit privileges can access everything users with view privileges can.  Finally, users with view privileges can only access pages/items that have view privileges (or pages with no authorization scheme specified).